# Javascript to replace or strip inner html

Tags: javascript

I need to extract just `V1 BAE` from this html:

```
<ul class="checkout-bar">
    <li> Info for V1 BAE </li>
</ul>
```

So far I have this:

```
function() {
    var element = document.querySelector('ul.checkout-bar > li').textContent;
    return element;
}
```

But it returns this:

\n\t\t\t\tInfo for V1 BAE\t\t\t

I need to just have the value `V1 BAE` so need to strip out all the '\n\t\t\t\tInfo for ' and '\t\t\t'.

Comment: do you need to extract this exact string or need more generic solution?

Comment: Easy.... `var result = 'V1 BAE';`

Answer (score 3):

You can use a combination of [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and [`String#trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) :

```
.replace('Info for','').trim();
```

**Demo:**

```js
var element=document.querySelector('ul.checkout-bar > li').textContent.replace('Info for','').trim();
console.log(element);
```

```html
<ul class="checkout-bar">
<li> Info for V1 BAE  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what if the element is like this `<li> Info for V1 BAE lel </li>`

Comment: @RaajNadar Then OP should clarify his question.

Comment: I am just asking is that possible with this solution??

Answer (score 3):

Use `replace` to replace `Info for` with `null` and then `trim()` the result to remove preceding and succeeding white spaces:

```js
function test() {
  var element=document.querySelector('ul.checkout-bar > li').textContent;
  var res = element.replace('Info for', '').trim();
  return res;
}

console.log(test());
```

```html
<ul class="checkout-bar">
  <li> Info for V1 BAE  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to capture things out of a string. The below example returns a collection containing all matches of this regex, and you can select which one you wish to return by using square brackets, eg: `result[0]`. This will also capture the required text even if the string is preceded or followed by anything.

```js
function test() {
  let element = document.querySelector('ul.checkout-bar > li').textContent;
  let regex = /.+Info\s+for\s+(\w+\s\w+).+/;
  let result = regex.exec(element);
  return result;
}

console.log(test()[0]);
console.log(test()[1]);
```

```html
<ul class="checkout-bar">
<li> Info for V1 BAE  </li>
</ul>
```

Note that if you specifically want to capture the string `V1 BAE`, you can replace `(\w+\s\w+)` with `(V1\sBAE)`, if there's a chance that the string will be different which you don't want to capture:

```js
function test() {
  let element = document.querySelector('ul.checkout-bar > li').textContent;
  let regex = /.+Info\s+for\s+(V1\sBAE).+/;
  let result = regex.exec(element);
  return result;
}

console.log(test()[0]);
console.log(test()[1]);
```

```html
<ul class="checkout-bar">
<li> Info for V1 BAE  </li>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: A regex is a solution, but a bit to complex for a problem like this one.

Comment: It's probably overkill but I think it's worth considering, especially if the example given is a much more simplified version of what OP requires. I get what you mean about it being a bit complicated for this problem though.